# What is the fastest way to regex find-and-replace a list of words in a datatable column in C#?

Tags: c#, c#-4.0

I'm currently using this method of iterating for every source line and every word replacement, is there a faster way?

I have the source text to find and replace in one column of datatable 'dataSource' and the match word and replace-to word in 2 columns of datatable 'wrData'

```cs
private void function()
{
    //Repeats for every row in dataSource           
    foreach (DataRow drRow in dataSource.Rows)
    {
        //Repeats for every row in WordReplace.csv
        foreach (DataRow wrRow in wrData.Rows)
        {
            string input = drRow["text"].ToString();
            string pattern;
            //Uses regex if not blank
            if (wrRow["source_regex_override"] != null && !string.IsNullOrEmpty(wrRow["source_regex_override"].ToString()))
            {
                pattern = wrRow["source_regex_override"].ToString();
            }
            //Use regex-fied source if regex override is blank
            else
            {
                string wr_source = wrRow["source"].ToString();
                pattern = @"\b" + wr_source + @"\b";
            }
            string replace = wrRow["change_to"].ToString();
            string result = Regex.Replace(input, pattern, replace, RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
            drRow["text"] = result;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't see much room for improvement. Instead of accessing the column three times, access it once. Note that `wrRow[col_name]` makes a lookup in a collection of columns.

```cs
string pattern = wrRow["source_regex_override"]?.ToString();
if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(pattern))
{
    string wr_source = wrRow["source"].ToString();
    pattern = @"\b" + wr_source + @"\b";
}
```

It uses the the [Null-conditional operators `?.`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/member-access-operators#null-conditional-operators--and-).

A better name for the variable `replace` (verb): `replacement` (noun).